# Passing a cookie into a fetch call

Tags: javascript, web-services, selenium, fetch

I am currently obtaining cookies from a specific url as follows:

```
const cookies = driver.manage().getCookies()
```

Note: driver is from Selenium WebDriver

My aim is to be able to pass these cookies in a fetch method. Perhaps with this kind of approach below

```
fetch(url, {
    credentials: "include",
    headers: cookies
});
```

The actual cookies being passed in above is an array that looks like this - below (with some obfuscation for privacy reasons):

```
[ { domain: 'somedomain.com',
    expiry: 12345434,
    httpOnly: false,
    name: 'JSESSIONID',
    path: '/',
    secure: false,
    value: '5766ti65ruir65e5uey454343' },
  { domain: 'somedomain.com',
    httpOnly: false,
    name: 'JSESSIONID',
    path: '/extra',
    secure: false,
    value: '5766ti65ruir65e5uey454343' } ]
```

Nothing seems to work however. Any ideas what the best way do this is?

Comment: To use cookies with fetch you have to the `credentials` option, `{credentials:'include'}`

Comment: @dotconnor thanks. I have already seen this in various posts, but I have not managed to get it working. Could you please show an example of how I can do that?

Comment: please provide a [mcve] of everything - including the cookie values and paths

Comment: @DanielA.White, please see the original question above for the updates - domain, value, expiry and path, have been obfuscated for privacy reasons. Everything else is exactly as the original cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cookies need to be like this

```
{cookie: 'name=value; name1=value1;'}
```

try

```
let heads = {'cookie' : ''};
cookies.forEach(c => heads['cookie'] += `${c['name']}=${c['value']};`)

fetch(url, {
    credentials: "include",
    headers: heads
});
```